# Highcharts and Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, highcharts

I am very new to js but I need to insert some html and js custom coding for a question I am asking in an online survey in Qualtrics.

I am specifically trying to add a highcharts element.

In the header of the survey, as specified in Qualtrics support page (http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/developer-tools/custom-programming/javascript-in-qualtrics/) I added these scripts to load highchart and jquery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script> var j = jQuery.noConflict(); </script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/highslide-software/draggable-points/master/draggable-points.js"></script>
```

As you can see I also added draggable-points.js, since I want to add something more or less very similar to the demo, in this page: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AyUbx/.

Then, in my Qualtrics question, in the js section, I added this code:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function(){
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    animation: false
},

title: {
    text: 'Highcharts draggable points demo'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['1yr', '5yr', '10yr']
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        point: {
            events: {

                drag: function (e) {

                    j('#drag').html(
                        'Dragging <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' + this.category + '</b> to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(e.y, 2) + '</b>');
                },
                drop: function () {
                    j('#drop').html(
                        'In <b>' + this.series.name + '</b>, <b>' + this.category + '</b> was set to <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '</b>');
                }
            }
        },
        stickyTracking: false
    },
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    },
    line: {
        cursor: 'ns-resize'
    }
},

tooltip: {
    yDecimals: 2
},

series: [{
    data: [0, 71.5, 106.4],
    draggableY: true
}]

});
});
```

It is more or less identical to the demo, at least the draggable line. It is not my final objective but for now I would love to at least manage to insert this.

Eventually, I inserted these html elements in the question body:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px">&nbsp;</div>

<div id="drag">&nbsp;</div>

<div id="drop">&nbsp;</div>
```

Nonetheless, the page remains blank when I try to load the survey, and I am not managing to figure out why. I doubt it is typos, since I almost copied the code entirely, but I guess for some reason highcharts is not loading appropriately.

Any suggestions about this?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Looking at the console may provide a hint as to whats wrong.

Comment: It could be that the highcharts code is using $ to refer to jquery instead of j (btw, people usually use $j to refer to jquery in Qualtrics). You may need to copy and modify highcharts.  Also the browser isn't going to be happy loading js from http instead of https. Use src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" for jquery. You'll need an https source for highcharts too.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console (developer tools) ?

Comment: Great, it was actually the https source to create problems! And since I am a beginner, as I said, I did not know it. Thank you so much!!!